# TRIGGERS "rebeldes" en MariaDB hacen la tarea al día siguiente, o próximo reinicio

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo el siguiente trigger que no quiere trabajar, pues lo realiza al día siguiente o reinicio próximo del servicio, relativamente seria lo mismo.
El trigger es el siguiente

```
BEGIN
declare sali text;
DECLARE entra TEXT;
IF obtenerestado() = 'anulando' THEN
SET entra = 'ANULACIÓN';
ELSE
SET entra = 'ENTRADA DE STOCK';
END IF;
IF obtenerestado() = 'vendiendo' THEN
SET sali = 'VENTA';
ELSE
SET sali = 'SALIDA DE STOCK';
END IF;
IF (NEW.especial != OLD.especial) then
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, nombrenuevo, nombreanterior, host) VALUES( obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'CAMBIO DE PRODUCTO A VENTA FRACCIONARIA',NEW.especial, OLD.especial, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.proveedor != OLD.proveedor) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, nombrenuevo, nombreanterior, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'CAMBIO DE PROVEEDOR',(SELECT nombre FROM proveedores WHERE id = NEW.proveedor), (SELECT nombre FROM proveedores WHERE id = OLD.proveedor), CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.categoria != OLD.categoria) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, nombrenuevo, nombreanterior, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'CAMBIO DE CATEGORÍA',(SELECT nombre FROM categoriadeproductos WHERE id = NEW.categoria),(SELECT nombre FROM categoriadeproductos WHERE id = OLD.categoria), CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.nombre != OLD.nombre) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, nombrenuevo, nombreanterior, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'CAMBIO DE NOMBRE',NEW.nombre, OLD.nombre, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.cantidad > OLD.cantidad) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, datoextra, datoanterior, datonuevo, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, entra,(NEW.cantidad - OLD.cantidad), OLD.cantidad, NEW.cantidad, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.cantidad < OLD.cantidad) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, datoextra, datoanterior, datonuevo, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, sali, (OLD.cantidad - NEW.cantidad), OLD.cantidad, NEW.cantidad, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF  (NEW.tipodeproducto != OLD.tipodeproducto) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, datonuevo, datoanterior, nombrenuevo, nombreanterior, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'CAMBIO DE TIPO DE PRODUCTO', (SELECT nombre FROM tipodeproducto WHERE id = OLD.tipodeproducto), (SELECT nombre FROM tipodeproducto WHERE id = NEW.tipodeproducto), (SELECT nombre FROM tipodeproducto WHERE id = OLD.tipodeproducto), (SELECT nombre FROM tipodeproducto WHERE id = NEW.tipodeproducto), CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.cantidadbultocerrado != OLD.cantidadbultocerrado) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, datoextra, datoanterior, datonuevo, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'CAMBIO DE BULTO CERRADO',(NEW.cantidadbultocerrado - OLD.cantidadbultocerrado), OLD.cantidadbultocerrado, NEW.cantidadbultocerrado, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.cantidadbultoabierto < OLD.cantidadbultoabierto) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, datoextra, datoanterior, datonuevo, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'SALIDA DE BULTO ABIERTO', (OLD.cantidadbultoabierto - NEW.cantidadbultoabierto), OLD.cantidadbultoabierto, NEW.cantidadbultoabierto, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF  (NEW.cantidadbultoabierto > OLD.cantidadbultoabierto) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, datoextra, datoanterior, datonuevo, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'ENTRADA DE BULTO ABIERTO',(NEW.cantidadbultoabierto - OLD.cantidadbultoabierto), OLD.cantidadbultoabierto, NEW.cantidadbultoabierto, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.stockminimo != OLD.stockminimo) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, datoanterior, datonuevo, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'CAMBIO DE STOCK MINIMO', OLD.stockminimo, NEW.stockminimo, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.eliminado != OLD.eliminado AND NEW.eliminado = 1) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, datonuevo, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'BAJA DE PRODUCTO', NEW.cantidad, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
IF (NEW.eliminado != OLD.eliminado AND NEW.eliminado = 0) THEN
INSERT INTO movimientostock (empleado, idproducto, razondemovimiento, datonuevo, host) VALUES (obtenerempleado(), NEW.id, 'RESTAURACIÓN DE PRODUCTO', NEW.cantidad, CURRENT_USER());
END IF;
```

y las tablas serian las siguientes:
"Movimientostock"

```
CREATE TABLE `movimientostock` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fechademovimiento` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `idproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `razondemovimiento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `datoextra` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `datoanterior` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `datonuevo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `nombreanterior` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nombrenuevo` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `empleado` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `computadoraid` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `host` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `razondemovimiento` (`razondemovimiento`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=78320
;
```

Y productos:

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `categoria` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `proveedor` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `stockminimo` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `eliminado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `especial` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tipodeproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidadbultocerrado` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidadbultoabierto` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ultimamodificacion` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `eliminado` (`eliminado`),
    INDEX `ultimamodificacion` (`ultimamodificacion`),
    INDEX `id2` (`id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre_2` (`nombre`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=7313
;
```

Y la funcion para realizar la modificacion de estado seria la siguiente:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `obtenerestado`()
RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
RETURN (IFNULL((SELECT estado FROM terminales WHERE conexionactual = CURRENT_USER() LIMIT 1),''));
END
```

En el sistema realizo el cambio de estado en la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `terminales` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombrepc` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `computerid` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `imprimirticket` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `nombredeimpresora` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `cajaindependiente` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `grupo` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `empleadoactual` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `estado` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `conexionactual` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;
```

La idea del trigger seria la siguiente, al realizar una modificación en la tabla "Productos" se realiza un historial de las modificaciones en "movimientostock", de esta manera se registra todas las modificaciones.
El problema seria que en el momento se registra una venta re verifica que se encuentra en la base de datos, pero al día siguiente la fecha de venta realizada el dia anterior, se cambia a la fecha de reinicio del servicio de base de datos MariaDB. Se actualiza la fecha de modificación en la base de datos "movimientostock", Por ejemplo

> "11307"   "2017-06-26 17:12:59"   "QUERUBIN FRESH AEROSOL
>   LAVANDA"  "VENTA" "0.00"  "0.00"  "1.00"  "0" "USUARIO"

Al dia siguiente se encuentra asi

> "11307"   "2017-06-26 07:05:59"   "QUERUBIN FRESH AEROSOL
>   LAVANDA"  "VENTA" "0.00"  "0.00"  "1.00"  "0" "USUARIO"

no se porque realiza ese cambio, alguien Sabría cual seria la causa del tal alteración? por favor si espero que alguien me ayude muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `fechademovimiento DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` en la definición de la tabla? ¿Realmente necesitas ese `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`? Es probable que algún `REPLACE` o consulta similar que regenere el contenido te está modificando (regenerando) ese valor. Entiendo que en el cambio de día querías decir `2017-06-26 17:12:59` >>> `2017-06-27 07:05:59`.

Comment: no hace replace, hace insert, no entiendo porque haria replace, si es cierto queria decir que el cambio que realiza es la fecha unicamente, yo coloco default current timesstamp, para poder ingresar la fecha cunado se hace el registro, evito codigo al "INSERT INTO ...."

Comment: Colocar un `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` tiene implicaciones que debes conocer. Entre ellas es que existen consultas con efecto regenerativo (te he puesto el ejemplo de `REPLACE`) que afectan a su valor. Lo ideal (o la buena práctica) es que permitas a ese campo ser `NULL` y le des el valor que tú quieras durante su inserción (por ejemplo `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`). Ese valor se mantendrá inalterado ante cualquier consulta "regenerativa".